# Switching desktop environment from Unity?

Tags: unity, lightdm, unity-greeter

Basicall I have installed a few desktop environments. And if you are familiar with Unity, you know that the way switching works, is you get this sort of drop-down with all the environments installed, you then high-light the desired option and click "ok". So my problem is that I have quite a few installed, and OK button is outside of the screen, and I cannot find any way to scroll down? So in turn, I cannot switch my DE as a result.. any way around this?

Comment: Tried enter, tried arrow keys to scroll down, tried mousewheel.. Nothing works

Comment: Are there any scroll bars?  A way around this is running `sudo` `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selecting `gdm`

Comment: no scroll bars at all. And I ran this command, but it did nothing (no config screen appeared) i just entered the command and got the prompt straight back lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tab key to scroll down the list, then press enter to select the DE, then tab more until the OK button, then press enter to select and return to the password screen. Yes, it sucks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few solutions here:

1. You could change the default session to be what you want using `lightdm-set-defaults`. If you've already set a different session, this may not work, I think it will prefer the session you chose last. The session name should match the file name in `/usr/share/xsessions`, without the .desktop on the end. I think maybe the default session moves to the top of the list though, so this may still work for you.

   `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session <session>`
2. You can go to `/usr/share/xsessions` and rename the ones you don't want to something besides `<session>.desktop`, like `<session>.desktop.old`.  I think that will hide them. You could also just uninstall the desktop environments you don't want.

Lastly, please take a screen shot of this and [file a bug against unity-greeter](http://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-greeter) for this list not fitting properly.

Comment: I had filed a bug but it was ignored.

Comment: What's the bug #?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1050013